# How to manipulate an unicode string with bitwise operators?

Tags: postgresql, bit-manipulation

I wish to encrypt an Unicode string by using bitwise operators from my client (Dart) app, and send it to my PostgreSQL server where a function will decrypt it by using bitwise operators. But I don't find any info to respect, is it possible?

NOTE: with Dart I can convert a string into codes and they can be dealt with bitwise operators.

Comment: Bit strings support [Bitwise operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html).

Comment: Only to encrypt communication between the client and the database! Why not `ssl = on`?

Comment: It is enabled, but I need certain data is not obfuscated if web user tries to use some `Inspect` tool from client app.

Comment: You can count on a determined attacker decompiling all client side code,  don't give your business secrets to your users.

Answer (score 0):

So you receive a string of bytes which has postgresql type `bytea`,

Perform your bitwise operations on that

using built in bytesting operations. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-binarystring.html
or using pgcrypto https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html

Then use `convert_from( mangled_bytestring,'UTF8')` to convert it to unicode text.

`text` (and `varchar` etc) in postgresql is represented internally as UTF8 but this is well hidden from the user.